# Rectangle Diagonal Gradient Brush between two points

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, charts, linear-gradients

Within a Chart I have a `StartPoint` and `EndPoint`. Those `Points` create a line between them and a rectangle. Alongside this line I want the rectangle to be green and become transparent at the corners.

The gradient should preserve the points on resize of course.
Somehow I really cannt figure out how to do this, it really drives me crazy.

Thanks for your help.

[image]

edit:
If i use @Sheridans solution if will look like this:

[image][image]

Comment: "The gradient should preserve the points on resize of course." => To clarify this, can you show us what the gradient currently looks like on resize?  And can you show us how you are calculating the gradient stops?

Comment: I tried to calculate it based on the Points (2785,70) etc. but this didn't work. When I use sheridans example it only works when I have a square... which makes sense of course.

Comment: Can you show us a picture of how it currently looks when resized, so we can see the problem?

Comment: I added two more screenshots to the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps.

I have edited lineseries template using **BlurBitmapEffect** and I have added one more polyline with same Points so that we can achieve BlurBitmapEffect.

**for eg.**

```
  <Grid>
    <Polyline Points="0 1 1 0" Stroke="#9FBD5F" StrokeThickness="200" Stretch="Fill">
        <Polyline.BitmapEffect>
            <BlurBitmapEffect Radius="100"  KernelType="Box" />
        </Polyline.BitmapEffect>
    </Polyline>
    <Polyline Points="0 1 1 0" Stroke="#2DB14D" StrokeThickness="5" Stretch="Fill"/>
</Grid>
```

---

**xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication8.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"       
    xmlns:chartingToolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
    xmlns:visualizationToolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
    xmlns:Primitives="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.Primitives;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit" 
    Title="Window1" Height="500" Width="500">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="LineSeriesStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type chartingToolkit:LineSeries}">
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type chartingToolkit:LineSeries}">
                    <Canvas x:Name="PlotArea">

                        <!--You can use linergradient or visulbrush to give color to polyline -->

                        <!--or you can use additional polylines to achieve  this affect-->
                        <Polyline Fill="Transparent"  StrokeThickness="200" Points="{TemplateBinding Points}">
                            <Polyline.Stroke>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="#9FBD5F"></SolidColorBrush>
                            </Polyline.Stroke>
                            <Polyline.BitmapEffect>
                                <BlurBitmapEffect Radius="100"  KernelType="Box" />
                            </Polyline.BitmapEffect>
                        </Polyline>                        
                        <Polyline x:Name="polynine" Points="{TemplateBinding Points}" StrokeThickness="5"   Stroke="#2DB14D"/>
                    </Canvas>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<chartingToolkit:Chart x:Name="mcChart" >
    <chartingToolkit:LineSeries DependentValuePath="Value"  IsSelectionEnabled="True" IndependentValuePath="Key" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Style="{StaticResource LineSeriesStyle1}"/>
</chartingToolkit:Chart>
```

**c#**

```
public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadColumnChartData();
    }
    private void LoadColumnChartData()
    {
        ((LineSeries)mcChart.Series[0]).ItemsSource =
        new KeyValuePair<string, int>[]{
        new KeyValuePair<string,int>("Project Manager", 13),
        new KeyValuePair<string,int>("CEO", 23),};

    }
```

Result

[image]

**Update** add this in lineseries template.

```
                <Polyline Fill="Transparent"  StrokeThickness="200" Points="{TemplateBinding Points}">
                            <Polyline.Stroke>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="#9FBD5F"></SolidColorBrush>
                            </Polyline.Stroke>
                            <Polyline.Effect>
                                <BlurEffect Radius="100"  KernelType="Box" />
                            </Polyline.Effect>
                        </Polyline>
```

Comment: Hello Heena, thanks for your anwer. This is a very good - and I think the only valid - solution. Unfortunatly the `BlurBitmapEffect` is deprecated: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.media.effects.blurbitmapeffect(v=vs.110).aspx Do you have an example using a regular Effect?

Comment: @JohannesWanzek Yes it also working with Effect.please see update.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot define a `LinearGradientBrush` using exact co-ordinate `Point`s. Instead, we specify `Point`s in an imaginary rectangle and usually with dimensions between `0` and `1`. From the [`LinearGradientBrush` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.lineargradientbrush(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN:

> A LinearGradientBrush paints an area with a linear gradient. A linear gradient defines a gradient along a line. The line's end points are defined by the StartPoint and EndPoint properties of the linear gradient. A LinearGradientBrush brush paints its GradientStops along this line.
>
> The default linear gradient is diagonal. In the default, the StartPoint of a linear gradient is (0,0), the upper-left corner of the area being painted, and its EndPoint is (1,1), the lower-right corner of the area being painted. The colors in the resulting gradient are interpolated along the diagonal path.

You can adjust the `StartPoint` and `EndPoint` properties to make the gradient better fit your target control, but the `GradientStop`s should look something like this:

```
<Rectangle>
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
            <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Transparent" />
            <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="LightGreen" />
            <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="Transparent" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

This code will result in something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer @sheridan but what happens if you resize the window?

Comment: The gradient will move with the `StartPoint` and `EndPoint` property values rather than the Window dimensions. However, these properties are `DependencyProperty`s so you should be able to data bind appropriate values to them to make it work.

Comment: Yeah and that's excaclty the question: How does this work? I mean a GradientBrush I can also do by myself.